# Path expected for Join in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have 2 tables:

[image: tables]

In my GnrlOrgChargeCode.java file, I have:

```
    private Set<IOrgChargeCodeCond> orgChargeCodeConds;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "gnrlOrgChargeCode", targetEntity = OrgChargeCodeCond.class,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public Set<IOrgChargeCodeCond> getOrgChargeCodeConds() {
        return orgChargeCodeConds;
    }

    public void setOrgChargeCodeConds(Set<IOrgChargeCodeCond> orgChargeCodeConds) {
        this.orgChargeCodeConds = orgChargeCodeConds;
    }
```

and in My OrgChargeCodeCond file:

```
    private IGnrlOrgChargeCode gnrlOrgChargeCode;
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = GnrlOrgChargeCode.class,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ORG_CHARGE_CODE_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    public IGnrlOrgChargeCode getGnrlOrgChargeCode() {
        return gnrlOrgChargeCode;
    }
    public void setGnrlOrgChargeCode(IGnrlOrgChargeCode gnrlOrgChargeCode) {
        this.gnrlOrgChargeCode = gnrlOrgChargeCode;
    }
```

and my Hibernate query is:

```
from GnrlOrgChargeCode gocc left join OrgChargeCodeCond occc where gocc.orgId = ?
```

but I get an error:

> Path expected for join!

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need a query like `from GnrlOrgChargeCode gocc left fetch join gocc.orgChargeCodeConds occc where gocc.orgId = ?`. Apart from that, entity joins are supported as of version 5.1. Since you get this error it seems you are using an older version. I would recommend you to update soon as you will most probably not receive any substantial support/help for older versions.